# How to get methods info on console in java

Tags: java, methods

I usually follow the **documentation** of java when i am online but when i am offline is it possible to see methods of particular class on **console** or any other way.

Comment: You can attempt to learn reflection. `java.lang.reflect`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can view the methods on console by typing this:-

```
javap java.io.BufferedReader
```

Instead of `java.io.BufferedReader` you can see any class methods by same syntax.
2nd way :-
Every JDK bundle have src.zip/src.rar you just extract that and and compile the java code by `javadoc` it will automatically make the java file to html file which is same as oracle documentation means you can access it offline also.Syntax:-

```
javadoc *.java
```

it will take all java files in folder make html files w.r.t that java file.

Answer (score 1):

If you use some specific kind of IDEs they may show you some of java doc, for example "NetBeans" or "Eclipse" have this ability.

A view from the Eclipse IDE.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can download the API [here](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/documentation/java-se-7-doc-download-435117.html).

Answer (score 1):

object.(class).getDeclaredMethods